# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.6.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

Today I updated all my support libraries and buildtools to the latest version to support Android `N`. Once I updated everything and ran the app, I got an error in `InstanceId` generation method of `GCM` in my app. So, I searched and found solutions that suggested to update play-services too. After following all the SO questions and answers, I am stuck and can't move forward. Switching back to support libraries `23.x.x` is not an option as I want to target Android `N`.

Here is how my project level `build.gradle` files look:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

App level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
//        maven { url 'http://hansel.io/maven' }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
//        classpath 'io.hansel.preprocessor:preprocessor:1.0.+'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
//apply plugin: 'io.hansel.preprocessor'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    signingConfigs {

    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.android'
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 47
        versionName "1.3.2"
        renderscriptTargetApi 24
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".dev"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "example-debug"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            resValue "string", "app_name", "example"
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
            // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
            // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
            minSdkVersion 16
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
//    maven { url 'http://hansel.io/maven' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.8.1+'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp:0.8.1+'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.github.liuguangqiang.swipeback:library:1.0.2@aar'
    compile 'me.imid.swipebacklayout.lib:library:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.2359media:EasyAndroidAnimations:0.8'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.0.+'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.4'
    compile 'com.github.ppamorim:dragger:1.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.2.0'
//    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
//    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.dotloop:aosp-exif:be25ae51ec'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp', module: 'okhttp'
        transitive = true;
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is the error I am getting:
[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit**

My google play services is also updated.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I solved it myself. Here is what I did:

1. Removed `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.6.1'` and then compiled the project
2. It gives `missing api_key error` because `GCM` got shifted to `Firebase` and so the `google-services.json` file does not work
3. To fix this, simply update the `google-services.json` file with the new generated file which uses Cloud messaging from Firebase
4. After this, I compiled and got another error that `@drawable/powered_by_google_dark` is missing from the project as I am using Places Autocomplete API. To fix this, add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.0'` to dependencies

Answer (score 5):

Today I had the same problem. This solved the problem for me:

Open the stand alone Android SDK Manager. In the Extras section the "Google Play Services" were at the latest version, but the "Google Repository" after updating the "Google Repository" from version 33 to 35, the problem was gone.

Comment: I had a similar problem... something crashed during upgrading Android/Studio and SDKs. When I came back to SDK Manager both `Google Play Services` and `Google Repository` were not installed at all. After (re)installing them things worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have the latest google play services, just click the link and android studio will offer a dialog to install it.

Comment: I clicked the link, nothing is happening.

Comment: Have you tried to use 9.6.0 instead of 9.6.1. I don't think there is a 9.6.1 yet

Answer (score 1):

Set all play service dependencies to 9.6.0. 9.6.1 hasn't released yet. If the problem still occurs, install latest google play service and repository in your android studio.

Comment: I changed all dependencies to 9.6.0 but still I am getting the same error. Also, my play services is updated too. See the edit.

Comment: try to change this line in your project level build.gradle `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'`. found this from [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/229) reference.

Comment: Still same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well sometime it happens when you are not connected to the internet.
Connect to internet and rebuild your project and the error will be gone.
Worked for me this way.